# how to use [ngClass] for multiple class conditions Angular4

Tags: html, angular

currently my div looks like this:

```
<div class="class-a" [ngClass]="{'class-b': !person.something}">
```

now I want to have another condition...

so now I want this div to be of class-a If something class-b If something else class-c

how should I do this?

im using angular 4.

thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add it like properties to an object literal:

```
[ngClass]="{'class-b': !person.something, 'other-condition': isOther }"
```

Comment: @MNY see New Answer

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to return a string from the component if you think you need more complex logic, or know there will only be one. This might be more testable.

Whatever string you return will be rendered as a class(es)

```
[ngClass]="renderClass()"

renderClass() {
  switch(this.user.theme){
    case "dark":
       return "dark-theme"
    case "light":
       return "light-theme"
  }
}
```

Comment: The function "renderClass" will be called numerous times since it will be called every time the change detection runs (put a console.log in it to see how much it's called!). Therefore it's better to use a pipe instead of a function as explained in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50227306/3149048

Answer (score 4):

The better way for use this Syntax `ngStyle` Because,
it's Not Completed Answer.

If you want to toggle some classes like `text-info` Or `text-danger` for `<i>` tag (

```
some exp ? 'text-info' : 'text-danger'
```

).

The best answer is array not object.

```
[ngClass] = "[some exp ? 'text-info' : 'text-danger', ...]"
```

GoodLuck

Comment: this one worked for me where one of them did not necessarily use an expression and I wanted to output the actual value `[ngClass]="[dropdownOpen ? 'open': '', selectedDosing.type]"`