# Angular 2 ngClass function

Tags: angular, css, ng-class

Hi I was in the midst of creating a wizard/step component.
How can I use the `ngClass` to return css classes based on `->`?

I have 5 steps, let's say the user is in the 3rd step. All the previous steps should return a css class named `active` and the current step (step 3) returns css class `active` and all the steps after step 3 should return `inactive` css class.

```
<div class="step actived">
                    <span [ngClass]="displayActiveness()">Step 1
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <div class="step" [ngClass]="displayActiveness()">
                    <span>Step 2
                    </span>
                </div>
.....
```

TS:

```
displayActiveness(status) {
        if (this.statusSelected === 'step3') {
            return 'active';
        } else if (
        this.statusSelected === 'step4' || this.statusSelected === 'step5'){
            return 'inactive';
        }
        else if (
            this.statusSelected === 'step1' || this.statusSelected === 'step2'){
                return 'actived';
            }
    }
```

I am stuck. Can someone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the issue now? currently function in ts is accepting a parameter but you are not passing any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not set your statusSelected to number and it would be easy to manage?

TS:

```
statusSelected: number = 1; //step 1 by default
....
displayActiveness(status) {
    if (this.statusSelected === status) {
      return 'active';
    }
    if (this.statusSelected > status) {
      return 'actived';
    }
    if (this.statusSelected < status) {
      return 'inactive';
    }
}
```

HTMl:

```
<div class="step"  [ngClass]="displayActiveness(1)">
    <span>Step 1</span>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="step" [ngClass]="displayActiveness(2)">
    <span>Step 2</span>
</div>
```

with this, next step could be only:

```
nextStep() {
    this.statusSelected++;
}
```

Comment: TY men, in angular V15 it work.

Answer (score 3):

Check the following [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivytam?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

`component.html`

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index">
        <span class="step" [ngClass]="displayActiveness(i)">
            {{step}} 
        </span>
        <button (click)="chooseStep(i)">Click me</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  currentStep = 0;
  steps = ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step4', 'step5'];

  chooseStep(index) {
    this.currentStep = index;
  }

  displayActiveness(index) {
    console.log('displayActiveness called')
    if (index > this.currentStep) {
      return 'inactive';
    } else {
      return 'active';
    }
  }

}
```

When you check the console, you'll see `displayActiveness` method gets called 10 times when you click on `Click me` button. This is because of angular change detection mechanism. When something happens to trigger change detection, angular will go through your template and call everything. So, generally it's not a good idea to call functions within templates. But, let's say you absolutely need to do so. Then, you can use pipes.

Check this second [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xaay8c?file=src%2Fapp%2Factive.pipe.ts)

In this example, I moved the logic of `displayActiveness` method to a Pipe, so that it only gets executed when the inputs change. It may not differ much in your example but think of a much more complicated method. You would not want angular to call your complicated method every time user does something.

`active.pipe.ts`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'activePipe'
})
export class ActivePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(index, currentStep) {
    console.log('pipe called')
    if (index > currentStep) {
      return 'inactive';
    } else {
      return 'active';
    }
  }
}
```

Changing `ngClass` to following

```
<span class="step" [ngClass]="i | activePipe: currentStep">
    {{step}} 
</span>
```

Comment: The idea of using a pipe here instead of a function is so much better!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, You can iterate over loop and set active class to your step like this -

```
<div class="step" [ngClass]='{"active" : activeClassList[0]}'>
  <span>Step 0</span>
</div>
<div class="step" [ngClass]='{"active" : activeClassList[1]}'>
  <span>Step 1</span>
</div>
<div class="step" [ngClass]='{"active" : activeClassList[2]}'>
  <span>Step 2</span>
</div>
<div class="step" [ngClass]='{"active" : activeClassList[3]}'>
  <span>Step 3</span>
</div>
<div class="step" [ngClass]='{"active" : activeClassList[4]}'>
  <span>Step 4</span>
</div>
<div class="step" [ngClass]='{"active" : activeClassList[5]}'>
  <span>Step 5</span>
</div>

settingActiveClass() {
     for(let i=0; i < this.userLevel; i++) {
       this.activeClassList[i] = 'active';
     }
   }
```

## [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfjaut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)