# Apply Overridden SCSS to Angular Component Conditionally

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I am trying to override the css for an Angular-Material component. I am using the

```
encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
```

to override in order to avoid the deprecated `/deep/` or `::ngdeep` .

so my SCSS looks like this

```
.some-class {
  margin: 50px
}

.some-class .mat-form-field-wrapper {
  color: red;
}
```

and my html looks like this

```
<div class="input-field">
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="some-class">
      <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="password" required />
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

but I want to apply the property `color: red` only when a boolean is false. I tried to use ngClass but how do I appply the entire selector (`.some-class .mat-form-field-wrapper`) in the ngClass syntax.

my HTML with ngclass (incomplete)

```
<div class="input-field">
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="some-class" [ngClass]="{
        ' *some way to get the class here* ':
          !passwordsRequirementSatisfied && f.password.touched
      }">
      <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="password" required />
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Is there any way in css or scss that I can assign the entire selector `.some-class .mat-form-field-wrapper` to a variable or a placeholder class or a different class so that I can use that variable/placeholder class directly with the [ngClass] syntax.

Comment: does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass?rq=1

Comment: it actually doesn't because in my case, the class selector is complex and not a single class which can be applied directly

Comment: then you can apply `[ngClass]="someMethod(variable)"` and create a method that will return class name as string

Comment: not sure how that will work. Can you elaborate?

Comment: check first example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50227306/9074272). For multiple classes you can combine it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18871805/9074272)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```css
.some-class.is-invalid .mat-form-field-wrapper {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
   <mat-form-field
    appearance="outline"
    class="some-class"
    [class.is-invalid]="!passwordsRequirementSatisfied && f.password.touched">
      <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="password" required />
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```