# ngClass combining multple conditions?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-class

How do I combine multiple conditions in Angular? im using angular 12 at the moment.

example:

`[ngClass]="condition1 ? 'className1': 'classname2'"`
this works if condition 1 is true or false.

now how to add multiple?

`[ngClass]='condition1 ? 'className1' : 'classname2' && conditionX ? 'classNameY' : 'classNameZ'"`

only the first condition seems to be checked, anything else after the && doesn't show up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 ngClass function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226800/angular-2-ngclass-function)

Comment: Use a function to evaluate your classname, this enable you to do everything you want. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226800/angular-2-ngclass-function

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do a function, but i'd like to keep it in html. it seems like a simple condition, shouldn't require a function just to have multiple.   I'm hoping someone can come up with a solution in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple conditions you can do like this:

```
[ngClass]="[ condition1 ? 'className1' : 'className2', conditionX ? 'classNameY' : 'classNameZ']"
```

separate each condition with ','

Comment: perfect, i was looking for this. i was using these { }  but should've tried [ ] 

awesome, exactly what i wanted. thank you

Answer (score 1):

For multiple conditions classes to apply refer Angular Docs. It has good explanation. [Link](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Comment: RTFM, is a bit short for an answer. You should elaborate it and give some hints in the context.

Answer (score 1):

Using an object you can handle multiple conditions

```
<div [ngClass]="{'firstClass': true, 'secondClass': true, 'thirdClass': false}">
     // your code...
</div>
```